# How to find similar values from two columns of different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have two data frames that look like this

```
df1
c1           c2   c3   c4   c5   c6   c7
2006-01-02 10:45 xxx0 yyy0 zzz0 rrr0 sss0
2006-01-02 11:00 xxx1 yyy1 zzz1 rrr1 sss1
2006-01-03 11:15 xxx2 yyy2 zzz2 rrr2 sss2
2006-01-03 11:30 xxx3 yyy3 zzz3 rrr3 sss3
2006-01-04 11:45 xxx4 yyy4 zzz4 rrr4 sss4
2006-01-05 11:00 xxx5 yyy5 zzz5 rrr5 sss5

df2
c1           c2     c3   c4 
2006-01-02  10:45  aaa0 bbb0 
2006-01-03  11:30  aaa1 bbb1
2006-01-04  10:40  aaa2 bbb2
2006-01-05  11:00  aaa3 bbb3
```

I want to edit the two columns of df1 such that it contains values that are common from  column c1 and c2 of df1 and df2

**Output:**

```
df1
c1           c2   c3   c4   c5   c6   c7
2006-01-02 10:45 xxx0 yyy0 zzz0 rrr0 sss0
2006-01-03 11:30 xxx3 yyy3 zzz3 rrr3 sss3
2006-01-05 11:00 xxx5 yyy5 zzz5 rrr5 sss5
```

What Ive tried is this

```
dfnewdate = df1[(df1[c1].isin(df2[c1])]
df1 = dfnewdate
dfnewtime = df1[(df1[c2].isin(df2[c2])]
df1 = dfnewtime
```

It was successfully filtered out the date except that it left out the first row of df1 and did not filter out the time (it still has the second row of old df1).

```
My output
df1
c1           c2   c3   c4   c5   c6   c7
2006-01-02 10:45 xxx0 yyy0 zzz0 rrr0 sss0
2006-01-02 11:00 xxx1 yyy1 zzz1 rrr1 sss1
2006-01-03 11:15 xxx2 yyy2 zzz2 rrr2 sss2
2006-01-03 11:30 xxx3 yyy3 zzz3 rrr3 sss3
2006-01-05 11:00 xxx5 yyy5 zzz5 rrr5 sss5
```

Is there something wrong with my code? is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: You want the output to have the same for both `c1` and `c2` values?

Comment: I want the output of df1⋂df2

Comment: Please share the data in a format which is convenient for others to use.

Comment: I updated the details

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I'll show you three.

1) Using `.loc` and `.isin()`

```
df1.loc[(df1['c1'].isin(df2['c1']))&(df1['c2'].isin(df2['c2']))]
```

2) Using `.join()` (with an inner join when you set each column to the index, you could use `.merge` just as easily)

```
df1.set_index(['c1','c2']).join(df2.set_index(['c1','c2']), how = 'inner').reset_index()
```

3) Using `pd.concat()` with `.duplicated()`. Here you combine both your df column wise, then look for the rows that are duplicated.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df3[df3.duplicated()]
```

EDIT:

This should work:

```
df1.loc[(df1['c1']+' '+df1['c2']).isin(df2['c1']+' '+df2['c2'])]
```

Comment: none of the codes works. Im sorry if i did not state it clearly but the dataframes that i actually have, have different shapes. i just gave the columns of data frame i want to filter out

Comment: The first one that you gave was not able yo filter out the table, while the second code gave an error of `ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index name`. and i was not able to use the last code since the two data frames have different shapes

Comment: You will need to provide a more representative example. If your example df doesn’t match what you have then no one can help...